# How can I tell if the coefficient is negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simple question that I can't find an answer to. I am trying to figure out what my book means by 'if the coefficient is negative'. They don't explain this at all, so that is why I am asking. Here is the equation:

$$y = -2 + \frac12\cot\left(\frac{2\pi}3x + 4\pi\right)$$

"After selecting the general shape of the graph, we need to decide if the ghraph needs to be reflected across the x axis. This is only necessary if the coefficient of the trigonometric function is negative. "

Okay so not looking for answer I can do that, I am only trying to understand this better. What is the coefficient?

Comment: In this case, it is $1\over2$.  The coefficient of a term is the constant portion that acts as a scaling factor on that term.

Comment: Please note that $\pi$ is spelled Pi.  Also, to format your equations it helps to encompass them using `$` characters: `$y = -2 + 1/2\cot((2\pi/3)x + 4\pi)$` becomes $y = -2 + 1/2\cot((2\pi/3)x + 4\pi)$.

Comment: So the coefficient is the number that is to the left of the trigonometric function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of a trig function in a case such as this is the real number by which it is multiplied. In this case, that number is $\frac{1}{2}$. Note that the positioning doesn't matter: $cot(x) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ has coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ also.

Comment: OK! Thank you! This makes sense. Would have been nice if my book said that.